# What's the definition of $\bar\psi$ in QCD?

Tags: fermions, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, isospin-symmetry, color-charge

This is a two part question.

1. What is the definition of $\bar\psi$ in QCD?

In QED I know that $\bar\psi=\psi^\dagger\gamma^0$, but in QCD we also have flavor and/or color space. In particular, I'm reading [Klevansky's review of the Nambu–Jona Lasinio model](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.64.649) of QCD, in which the Lagrangian and several symmetry transformations seem to invole the Pauli isospin matrices $\tau$.

2. How can I prove the following symmetry transformation, given in Eq. (2.8) of the source cited above?

$$\psi\to e^{-i(\tau\cdot\theta)\gamma_5/2}\psi \Rightarrow (\bar\psi\psi)\to (\bar\psi\psi)\cos\theta-(\bar\psi i\gamma_5\tau\cdot\hat\theta)\sin\theta.$$

Obviously (1) is necessary in order to answer (2), but at any rate I'm confused as to how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a NJL model with two flavors $(u,d)$, the field $\psi$ is defined as
$$\psi=\begin{pmatrix}  u \\ d  \end{pmatrix},$$
being $u$ and $d$ ordinary Dirac spinors. This means that, in your transformation, the SU(2) part applies to $\psi$ while $\gamma_5$ goes on the single Dirac spinors. Remebering that $\gamma_5^2=I$, you have
$$
e^{-i{\mathbf\tau}\cdot{\mathbf\theta}\gamma_5/2}=\cos\left(\frac{|{\mathbf\theta}|}{2}\right)-i\frac{{\mathbf\tau}\cdot{\mathbf\theta}}{|{\mathbf\theta}|}\gamma_5\sin\left(\frac{|{\mathbf\theta}|}{2}\right)
$$
that yields
$$
e^{-i{\mathbf\tau}\cdot{\mathbf\theta}\gamma_5/2}\psi=\cos\left(\frac{|{\mathbf\theta}|}{2}\right)\begin{pmatrix}  u \\ d  \end{pmatrix}-i\frac{{\mathbf\tau}\cdot{\mathbf\theta}}{|{\mathbf\theta}|}\sin\left(\frac{|{\mathbf\theta}|}{2}\right)\begin{pmatrix}  \gamma_5u \\ \gamma_5d  \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: As for my question 1, is $\bar\psi$ then the transpose of $\psi$ in flavor space, with $u$ and $d$ also becoming $u^\dagger\gamma^0$ and $d^\dagger\gamma^0$? The multiplication by $\gamma^0$ for the spinor part makes me wonder whether there is also a multiplication by some $\tau$ matrix for the flavor part.

Comment: You are right and this is the interesting part as $\gamma_5$ anticommutes with $\gamma_0$ and this gives exactly the transformation you get for $\bar\psi\psi$.

Comment: Coming back to this (weeks later), I'm still confused about how the $\tau\cdot\theta$ turns into $|\theta|/2$. I have been assuming $\tau\cdot\theta=\theta_1\tau_1+\theta_2\tau_2+\theta_3\tau_3$ for arbitrary real parameters $\theta_i$. Is this true? If so, how does the $\tau\cdot\theta$ disappear from the $\cos$ term?

Comment: Never mind, now I see it: commutation relations for Pauli matrices show that $(\tau\cdot\theta)^2 = |\theta|^2$, and that does the trick.